# Is there a way for fuzzing Swing applications?

Tags: java, swing, fuzzing

Back in the old days, PalmOS had an emulator that could generate random events ("tap here, enter garbage in that text field, ...") for testing how applications would handle them (called "Gremlins"). This is a bit like fuzzing, but for a GUI. Is there an easy (existing) way to do that in a Java Swing application?

Edit:

Please note that I don't want to be able to specify, which events are fired. I'd like some code to *automatically generate* and fire random (as in "Math.random()") events. The probability that the events do something useful or find a bug is pretty small. But that is offset by firing many events.

Comment: Lets hope your app cannot open a "open file" dialog then subsequently delete all the contents of your drive.

Comment: If that's a problem with the interface, let's hope I find it this way before the user does.

Comment: Any application on Windows allows you to delete and create folders in a Open File dialog. Its not necessarly a bug in the app.

Comment: I wrote "if". Also, I'm more on the hunt for errors that are triggered by random input. It's one thing to put a test user in front of your program and ask her to click around. It's a totally different thing to let a Gremlin hammer your program because that Gremlin doesn't care if the text field only accepts dates and crashes otherwise. http://geekandpoke.typepad.com/geekandpoke/2010/02/simply-explained-edge-cases.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [FEST](http://fest.easytesting.org/). It simplifies the process of functional-testing Swing GUIs by allowing to access Swing components by name and then interacting with them.

An example from FEST site:

```
dialog.comboBox("domain").select("Users");
dialog.textBox("username").enterText("alex.ruiz");
dialog.button("ok").click();
dialog.optionPane().requireErrorMessage()
                   .requireMessage("Please enter your password");
```

**Edit:**

Alternatively, what you are trying to achieve, should be really straightforward using Math.random(), a loop, findBomponentAt(int, int) and Robot class. Especially Robot class mitght be of use, as it has methods for spoofing mouse and keyboard events

Comment: That sounds cool, but is not what I want. I want automatic /random/ events fired. As in "Math.random()", not as in "Random Access Memory".

Comment: If so, then, whatever it is you are trying to achieve, should be really straightforward using [Math.random()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29), a loop, [findBomponentAt(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) and [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. Especially `Robot` class mitght be of use, as it has methods for spoofing mouse and keyboard events.

Comment: I've edited the original answer, so now you can. Glad I could help :-)